# Folder.Bind Method in Graph SDK client using C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

We need folder.bind similar method in Graph SDK using C#.

Below method works with Outlook Exchange services but for O365 user its not working.

```
var msgRootFId = new EWS.FolderId(EWS.WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new EWS.Mailbox(SMTPAddress));
msgRoot = EWS.Folder.Bind(service, msgRootFId, EWS.BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call one of the following endpoints. Instead of `id` you can use well-known folder name `msgfolderroot`

```
GET /me/mailFolders/{id}
GET /me/mailFolders/msgfolderroot

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/msgfolderroot
```

Resources:

[mailFolder resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[get mailFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)